# Windows 10 Last BIOS time incorrect

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

I have just built a new system, and at the same time purchased Windows 10 (previously a Win7 user). Among the many new features I've noticed that the 'Last BIOS time' in task manager shows an erroneously large number. The actual boot time is around 10-20 seconds, but task manager is currently showing 2296.4 seconds. Initially I thought it was a millisecond to second conversion error but 2.3s doesn't seem right either.

Does anyone know what is causing this incorrect value, and how to show the correct time.

[image: Task Manager]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much googling, and some experimentation of my own I found the following:

- A Reddit r/TechSupport post with a person having observed the same behaviour on a previous iteration of my motherboard. Notably this person found the time to be correct on the first cold boot, but then wrong on subsequent restarts. [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/3z10xb/last_bios_time_increases_on_x99_with_each_reboot/?st=izzztxvx&sh=458c5b91).
- A post on the Asus forum with the same problem and an enlightening answer indicating that the counter is not reset to 0 on a restart. [Source](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?87155-Last-BIOS-Time-in-Task-Manager-odd-result).

Having now observed the timer on the last few restarts, and shutdowns I can confirm the same behaviour as the posts. It appears that the counter is only reset to zero on a shutdown and power up, and a restart within windows does not reset to 0 as should be expected. The value seems to have a maximum value and overflows back to 0s, hence the seemingly random values of a few thousand seconds. This seems to be a poorly documented quirk of Windows 10 and X99 so I will update this answer as I gain more information.

Answer (score 1):

What is the 'Last BIOS' time?

https://www.howtogeek.com/265623/what-is-last-bios-time-in-the-windows-task-manager/

If it's showing incorrectly, it's likely a bug in the BIOS firmware, and there's not really anything you can do about it. It doesn't really matter anyway, as long as it's actually booting fast.

2.3s is also considerably fast - most machines average around 3-5s for a BIOS time

Comment: I came across that page whilst googling already, and although it talks about how to reduce the time it doesn't give any indication as to what could be causing such an error. Also I'm pretty sure that 2.3s is also not the correct value as it takes 10-20s for the full boot process.

Comment: That's the BIOS time not the boot time - that time measure the time for the BIOS to POST, not to boot. The site literally also says that incorrect values (such as 0s) are most likely due to bugs in the firmware...